# How should I implement delayed topic architecture in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

If my consumers fails to process the message for the time being, I want it to push to 5 minutes delayed Topic and if it fails to process from there also I want it to push to 30 minutes delayed topic. If it fails here as well, would like to push it to Dead-Letter-Queue.

**5 minutes delayed topic** : Consumer should listen after 5 minutes from first processing.

**30 minutes delayed topic** : Consumer should listen after 30 minutes from previous failure.

How should I design the delayed queue? It's easy to push to Kafka topic after failure but how should my consumer/listener listen that after 5 minutes or 30 minutes delay?

I am using SpringKafka for consumers to listen from a topic like below-

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic}")
public void receive1(String payload) {
    logger.info("Getting message on receiver-1");
    submitPayloadToExecutor(payload);
}
```

I have below implementation for my own project, can someone point out the fallback and any new suggestion ??

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic}")
    public void receive3(String payload) {

        logger.info("Getting message on receiver-3");
        submitPayloadToExecutor(payload);
    }

    private void submitPayloadToExecutor(String payload) {

        StartupService startupService = StartupServiceSingleton.INSTANCE.getStartupServiceInstance();

        ObjectMapper mapper = startupService.getConverter().getObjectMapper();

        PublishPostProcessorEntity publishPostProcessorEntity = null;
        try {
            publishPostProcessorEntity = mapper.readValue(payload, PublishPostProcessorEntity.class);
            
            sleepForDelayedPublishedEntity(publishPostProcessorEntity);

            // ... do some work

            topicExecutorService.submit(publishPostProcessorEntity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Work on exception
        }
    }

    private void sleepForDelayedPublishedEntity(PublishPostProcessorEntity publishPostProcessorEntity) {

        if (publishPostProcessorEntity instanceof DelayedPublishPostProcessorEntity) {

            DelayedPublishPostProcessorEntity delayedPublishPostProcessorEntity = (DelayedPublishPostProcessorEntity) publishPostProcessorEntity;

            // Fetch the topicName and sleep based on the configuration
            long pushedTimeStamp = delayedPublishPostProcessorEntity.getPushedTimeStamp();
            delayedPublishPostProcessorEntity.setComingTopicName(delayedPublishPostProcessorEntity.getNextTopicName());

            long currentTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (CMSKafkaConstants.FIVE_MINUTES_DELAYED_TOPIC
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(delayedPublishPostProcessorEntity.getNextTopicName())) {

                long timeElapsed = currentTimeStamp - pushedTimeStamp;
                if ((Long.parseLong(firstDelay)-timeElapsed) > 0) {
                    // wait for timeToWait
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(Long.parseLong(firstDelay)-timeElapsed);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } else if (CMSKafkaConstants.THRITY_MINUTES_DELAYED_TOPIC
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(delayedPublishPostProcessorEntity.getNextTopicName())) {

                long timeElapsed = currentTimeStamp - pushedTimeStamp;
                if ((Long.parseLong(secondDelay)-timeElapsed) > 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(Long.parseLong(secondDelay)-timeElapsed);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop and start consumers as needed via the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` (use `getListenerContainer(id).start()`).

Comment: Can you just elaborate this? When should I stop consumer and start it again? There maybe a case where failed events are keep on coming every second.

Comment: You can look at the timestamp of incoming records and stop the container when one comes in that is too recent - using MANUAL acks, by not acking such records before stopping the container, they will be redelivered.